How can I create a dictionary of all values of an enum in c#?
I wish to create a dictionary with an enum key by looping over all values of the enum, e.g.
public enum MyEnum
{
    First,
    Second,
    Third
}

Dictionary<MyEnum,int> myDict = new Dictionary<MyEnum,int>();
var types = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum));

int i = 1;

foreach (var val in types)
{
   myDict.Add(val,i);
   i++
}

Console.WriteLine(myDict[MyEnum.Second]);


Expected output:
2

(Yeah I probably shouldn't iterate and trust the ordering of a foreach like that, just an example)

Welp was searching for an hour but as usual, found the answer right after posting. I need to say .Cast() in the types line,
var types = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).Cast<MyEnum>();


You can avoid the cast (and the typeof) by using Enum.GetValues<MyEnum>() instead.

@EtiennedeMartel On newer versions of .NET, yes. Honestly though, FastEnum should be used since it is faster overall.

What do you mean, "newer"? It's been in there since .NET 5. That's four years old now.
